# application for a specific unique device

Tags: android

Is there any way to build application for a specific unique device? 
Suppose I have one android device and I want to create an apk file for that device only, that apk can't be get installed on any another device, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/726954) to get the unique device ID.

However, you won't be able to use this to restrict Google Play to restrict your app to this device only, instead, as @ThomasK suggests, you can add a check for this specific device id and finish() if it's not the specific device.

You can limit your app installing from play in many ways, but you cannot restrict it to that extent at a configuration level.

Comment: To extend this solution, you could decouple the installer and the payload, creating a lean application that existed simply to check the unique device ID and then, for a match, access the payload from a third-party location.  It is not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, Impossible

Answer (score 0):

There are two chances for your purpose:

1st:
 when the app starts (that means installing IS possible) you could get the `MODEL` of the device and if it is NOT the device you designed the app for, you could `finish()` the activity and the app.

getting the model:

```
String PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

2nd:
Afaik there is a possibility to control what devices are forbidden for your app in the `Google Play Store` maybe there is not only a Blacklist, but a Whitelist for this?

Answer (score 0):

> that apk can't be get installed on any another device, is it possible?

I am not sure about this.But you can decide whether to Enable certain feature based on Device.

Like you can programatically check device wifi mac address which is unique to each device.
If it don't match your criteria don't enable the feature.